# Mitigating low usb disk space error in backup scenario

Tags: backup, network-attached-storage, backupexec, synology

In our workplace we have setup a backup system consisting the Symantec Backup Exec 2010 R3 and Synology NAS

The backup are scheduled as follows

`Symantec Backup Exec` ---[1]---> `Synology Rack`  ---[2]---> `external usb`

Part `1` consists of the following back tasks:

1. System Back up - daily @ 18:00
2. Data Back up - daily @ 23:00
3. System setting Back up - weekly (saturdays) @ 20:00

Part `1` seems to work fine; Problems arise in part `2`, which consist of only one backup task

1. LUN backup - weekly (tuesdays) @ 06:00

Every Tuesday we receive the following auto-generated email: `USB disk 1 on your NAS device is running out of space; please take corrective action`,

followed by this email: `Local LUN Backup on your NAS device has failed. Please check the backup log for further information`

Is there a clever way of solving this situation. First thing that comes to my mind is somehow emptying the external USB drive, but how to do this automatically?

I am a newbie, so any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: I would start by looking at the back-up schedule in the Synology web interface. That is probably storing multiple copies of the data on the NAS to the USB drive, for which there is insufficient space. if your back-up requirements allow you could reduce the number of copies to the USB drive. Alternatively get a either a larger replacement or add a second USB drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure there's enough space on the disk. We use Synology as well and run into the same problems. Synology does not automatically delete "old" backups from the external disk if you're doing incremental backups or naming backup files differently with timestamps or other methods.

Basically, you have to do this manually while ensuring there's enough space on the disk for everything to fit at least once.

Comment: isn't there an overwrite option? or something close to that which can solve the issue?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is not. I actually just now had to delete some old backup files from our external disk. It's usually a weekly task.

Comment: posted on the official Synology forums, if there is any feedback will let you know; btw do you think our backup scheme is OK-ish?

Comment: Yes. Any off-site backup is better than nothing. As long as it's kept track of (low space alerts dealt with) it's a pretty solid solution.

Comment: I believe NAS allows running user defined scripts; wouldn't it be possible for us to have a script which would take care of the external USB space by formatting it? or maybe a more advanced script which deletes only backups up to date xx